# Unstacking rasters using "terra" package in R

Tags: r, raster, terra

Background: I am rewriting some scripts moving from "raster" package to "terra".

Problem: how to handle a raster with multiple layers

I know that in raster the 'stack' function was used, in terra it is enough to use c(...), see example below:

```
rast_example <- raster::stack(layer1, layer2, layer3)
rast_example <- terra::c(layer1, layer2, layer3)
```

But the other way around? What if I have to unstack, I know how to handle it in raster but not in terra, for instance this is how I would do it using raster

```
raster_list <- raster::unstack(rast_example)
```

How to do it in terra?

Probably this is a very stupid and basic question, but I got lost.
Thanks!

Comment: you can try `as.list(rast_example)`

Comment: yeah it is working fine. Actually now I see it, it was easy. Thanks a lot